# How to give more weight to Proper Nouns in scikit TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk

I am using `sci-kit`'s `TdidfVectorizer` to extract keywords from a list of scientific articles. There is an argument for stop_words, but I was wondering if I could give more weight/score to proper nouns such as "Bohr" or "Japan".

Will I have to implement my own custom `tfidf vectorizer` or can I still use this built in one?

```
tf = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents='ascii', 
                     analyzer='word',
                     ngram_range=(1,1),
                     min_df = 0,
                     stop_words = stopwords,
                     lowercase = True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your own postrpocessing to the TfIdf matrix for it.

At first you need to look through all the words indexes to find indexes for all the Proper Nouns, after that look through the matrix and increase weight for those indexes.